# Sending GET parameters in Restangular

Tags: angularjs, http, restangular

I'm using [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) in my project and earlier this code worked well for retrieving array of objects:

```
var params = {name: "Stack", surname: "Overflow"}
var service = Restangular.all('users')
service.getList(params)
```

Response from server was just an array of objects:

```
[
 {...},
 {...}
]
```

But now I added pagination, and my response now contains not an array, but an object which includes array:

```
{
   totalCount: 500,
   data: [
     {...},
     {...}
   ]
}
```

Also I changed `service.getList(params)` to `service.get(params)` (because `getList` expects only arrays).

And after this changes my GET parameters are not stringified, i.e. I see in debugger request like this:

`users/[object%20Object]`

but earlier (when using `getList` method) it worked as I expected:

`users?name=Stack&surname=Overflow`

What is the problem here?

Comment: My guess is that Restangular (a lib I'm not familiar with) is sticking to pure REST semantics and does not expect a straight GET to contain anything other than `/thing/id`. You'd be better off trying to configure the `getList` / *query* method to accept an object response

Answer (score 14):

I was able to solve it using this:

```
var params = {name: "Stack", surname: "Overflow"}
var service = Restangular.all('users')
service.customGET("", params) // first parameter is required, so just provide empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `customGETLIST` method, look this:

```
// https://myapi.com/users?name=Stack&surname=Overflow

Restangular.all('users').customGETLIST('', {
    name: "Stack", 
    surname: "Overflow"
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

customGETLIST(path, [params, headers]): Does a GET to the specific path. In this case, you expect to get an array, not a single element. Optionally you can set params and headers.

Documentation: [HERE](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#custom-methods)

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use **one**() and **get**(*params*):

```
var params = {name: "Stack", surname: "Overflow"};
var service = Restangular.one('users');
service.get(params).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
})
```